# selected state mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, list, state, selected

I am trying to combine a table select output with a piece of code I found to keep the selected state:

```
<select>
<?php
$desired_option = 'arsenal';
$arr = array('arsenal', 'aston villa', 'birmingham', 'blackpool', 'bolton');
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
$selected = ($arr[$i] == $desired_option) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
echo "<option value=\"{$arr[$i]}\" {$selected}>{$arr[$i]}</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select id="teams" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="teamid">
<? 
include('db.php');
$getTeams = mysql_query("SELECT name, id FROM team") or die(mysql_error());
while ($teamsData = mysql_fetch_array($getTeams))
{
?>    
<option value="<? echo $teamsData['id']; ?>" ><? echo $teamsData['name']; ?></option>
<? 
}
?>
</select>
```

I have tried everything. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="teams" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="teamid">
<? 
include('db.php');

$selected = 'team_to_be_selected';

$getTeams = mysql_query("SELECT name, id FROM team") or die(mysql_error());
while ($teamsData = mysql_fetch_array($getTeams))
{
?>    
<option value="<?php echo $teamsData['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($teamsData['name'] == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $teamData['name'];?></option>
<? 
}
?>
</select>
```